# Differences between singularity of total space and singularity of fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose in the category of varieties over a field $k$ of characteristic zero we have a fibration
\begin{equation}
\pi:X \rightarrow S
\end{equation}
Suppose further $S$ is a smooth. I know examples where $X$ is smooth, while some fibers of this family can become singular. In general, are there any kind of relations between the singularity of $X$ and the singularities of fibers?

Comment: For simplicity, let me assume that $S$ is a smooth curve. Then every singular point of $X$ is contained in a singular fiber. So, what other relation are you looking for?

Comment: Is this true in general for arbitrary smooth $S$?

Comment: Since every point in a smooth $S$ has a smooth curve passing through it, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are often relations between the singularities of the fibers and the singularities of the total space. An early example of such a relation is that if $X_s$ has rational singularities for all $s$ and $\pi$ is flat, then $X$ has rational singularities. This was proven by Elkik in "Singularities rationelles et deformations", Inventiones 47 (1978). Similar theorems have been proven for other classes of singularities - if you google about "deformations of ADJECTIVE singularities", where ADJECTIVE is replaced with the class of singularities you care about, you will probably find good discussion or papers about this fact.

Comment: can you give additional examples of when you can have a smooth total space but singular fibres? Is there a general theory about what effect the singularities of the fibres have on  the total space?

Comment: It depends on what you want and what your conditions are. Here's a cheap example: for any polynomial $f\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, we can get $V(f)\subset \Bbb A^n_k$ as the fiber over zero of $f:\Bbb A^n_k\to \Bbb A^1_k$, so any hypersurface singularity can be had in this way. For many classes of singularities, a statement like "if $f:X\to Y$ is a nice map and the fibers are BLAH singularities then $X$ has at worst BLAH singularities" is true, but the details are important and depend on the specific class of singularities. If you have more specific issues, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks this example is helpful. I posted a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577881/singular-fibrations-with-ade-singularities