# Singular Fibrations with ADE Singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

If we have a fibration (i.e. satsfying the homotopy lifting property) E $\rightarrow$ M with M a smooth complex manifold and E a potentially singular variety and the fibres having at worst ordinary double point singularities, what types of singular behaviors could we see in the total space E and under what circumstances would the total space E be smooth complex manifold. Specifically in the case I am thinking about the smooth fibres would be modeled on smooth K3-Surfaces and the singular fibres would be K3-Orbifolds. More generally if we have the same basic setup but the singular fibres have general ADE singularities what would be the implication for the total space, and are there conditions that one could put to ensure there are ADE singularities in the total space as well?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is the MathJax tutorial - you may wish to use it to format portions of your post. Secondly, this could use some specifics - do you assume $E,M$ to be complex manifolds, or schemes over $\Bbb C$ with some adjectives? What is your definition of a fibration (homotopy lifting property, flat family of schemes, etc)?

Comment: Hi, I revised the post. The actual context I am thinking of this relates to the work of Donaldson studying Fibrations of G2-Manifolds as described here https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08391. In this case the total space and base happen to be smooth real manifolds. However this is closely related to standard Lefshetz fibrations and for this reason I posed the question above in the complex context.

Comment: For the semiuniversal deformation of ADE singularities, its total space is certainly smooth (see page 9 in Slodowy's _Four Lectures on Simple Groups and Singularities_). In general, it depends on the local monodromy. I have a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3513160) about this question in ordinary double point, which might be useful to you.